# Looking for cannons in NSMB Wii

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-wii

New Super Mario Bros. Wii (also known as NSMB and NSMB Wii) is a very complex game and I cannot find any of the cannons. Do I need to take a secret exit for them, or do I buy them with starcoins?

Answer (score 1):

You will always know that a secret exit leading to a cannon is in a level if the level on the map has a road connecting to a cannon. In many cases, you should try to keep items, like propeller mushrooms and propeller boxes to get to out of reach areas.

Answer (score 0):

Star Coins are simply collectible and unlock levels after you've defeated the main boss level.

Secret exits are what you are looking for. Try looking for subtle hints that something is different in the game. Run into areas that look like walls but might contain a secret. Try to jump to places you'd never thought of before. Walkthroughs can sometimes ruin the fun, unless that's what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, you need to take seceret exits. Below are some helpful recouces:

Instructions on Gamfaqs
http://www.gameyum.com/super-mario-brothers/59199-new-super-mario-bros-wii-warp-cannon-guide/

Instuctions on Mecca Apps
http://meccaapps.blogspot.com/2013/12/nsmb-wii-guide.html

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Please don't just link elsewhere to answer your question.  Please summarize the information from the links to ensure your answer still stands if the links ever break.